# Update a Dataframe with more columns with a Dataframe with less columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In pandas, it's possible to update two dataframes when they have equal columns. In my case, they is a need to update a dataframe with more columns by df with fewer columns. Is this possible?. For clarity below is an illustration of the same

**df1 (the dataframe with fewer columns)**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["Mary", "Tobias", "Linus"], [16, 14, 10], [16, 17, 20]])
```

**df2, the parent dataframe that needs to be updated, has more columns**

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["Mary", "Tobias", "Linus", "Tonny", "Angela"], []])
```

**Desired output**

```
0  Mary  Tobias  Linus  Tonny  Angela
1    16     14     10   None    None
2    16      17    20   None    None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation you're looking for is an outer merge or in pandas:

```py
pd.merge(df1, df2,  how='outer')
```

This will add an extra column of `None`s at the end because your current definition of `df2` has one empty entry (which defaults to all cols as `None`).